# Help creating a tie pattern in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, patterns

I'm trying to replicate the pattern of F. Scott Fitzgerald's tie from "Midnight in Paris" in Illustrator.

[image: Tie]

I thought it would be easy enough, but have tried a lot of things with the white squares and gold background, and it always comes out something like this.

[image: Screenshot]

My first idea was one square.

[image: One square]

I don't know what to do anymore. Maybe I'm overthinking it

Comment: Think of it as a checkerboard. So the base pattern is 2 by 2 with 2 empty squares and 2 with content.

Comment: Oh, so like this? Sorry, I don't know if you can put pictures in comments but I'll do my best to make art with text that's understandable.  Blank space, square (new line underneath), square, blank space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple checkerboard using **brick by row** for an offset:

[image]

I would actually create a pattern of *only* the focus areas - just the little white box and what's inside it (replacing white with red in the image below, so it can be seen). Creating a no-fill, no-stoke, rectangle *behind* everything to define the actual tile boundaries. Then I'd apply another fill beneath the actual pattern for the flood fill:

[image]

---

Or create a second pinstripe pattern to use for the background fill (the red box above was set back to white for the image below):

[image]

Comment: I'm not home right now, but will definitely try this when I get back. Just wanted to let you know I've seen it and am not ignoring you.

Comment: No worries `:)`

Comment: I just noticed this now: is that blood on the tie?  Still not home by the way.

Comment: Catsup... darn street hot dogs... `:)`

Comment: I see. :) My more violent mind went to blood right away.